# MYSQL: Query with a two cases allways showing both cases

Tags: mysql

The Query in question is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t.name AS tname, 
      t.keyid AS tkeyid,
      t.task_group AS ttg,
      CASE WHEN (tgs.keyid = t.task_group AND p.keyid = tgs.proyect) THEN p.name ELSE 'N/A' END AS pname
      FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu, task_groups AS tgs, proyects AS p
      WHERE (tu.worker = 1 AND t.keyid = tu.task) ORDER BY tkeyid ASC;
```

The query should show me the p.name registered in proyects table when the condition of the case is met and N/A otherwise. There are serveral entries in tasks such that t.task_group = -1 so the condition will not be met. These are shown correctly in the results.

However if t.task_group is a positive number (an actual reference to a task_group) The query shows me two results like so:

```
+----------------------+--------+------+-------------------------------+
| tname                | tkeyid | ttg  | pname                         |
+----------------------+--------+------+-------------------------------+
| Sensor de frecuencia |    170 |   11 | biblioteca_perifericos_01     |
| Sensor de frecuencia |    170 |   11 | N/A                           |
```

Why is it doing this and how can I correct it?

Comment: Would need to see the other table structures and sample data but it seems like your query where clause is joining on more than one row (i.e. returns some sort of cross product). There must be two rows in task_groups with both worker = 1 and t.keyid = tu.task. In terms of refining the query that is where I'd start.

Comment: group by keyid does it work.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. If I only comment out the CASE then the query works as expected but it does not show me the pname (obviously). This would mean that the where clause is ok, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've kept at it and I found a query that does what I wanted. I'm leaving it here so that it might help someone with a similar problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      t.name AS tname, 
      t.keyid AS tkeyid,
      t.task_group AS ttg,
      CASE WHEN (t.task_group != -1) THEN (SELECT p.name FROM proyects AS p, task_groups AS tg WHERE tg.keyid = t.task_group AND tg.proyect = p.keyid) ELSE 'N/A' END AS pname
      FROM tasks AS t, task_users AS tu
      WHERE (tu.worker = 1 AND t.keyid = tu.task) ORDER BY tkeyid ASC;
```

This is simpler (conceptually, at least) since I just query for the datum that I want when the condition t.task_group = -1 is true.